# merging dataframes in pandas python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 10 dataframes and I'm trying to merge the data in them on the variable names. The purpose is to get one file which would contain all the data from the relevant variables

I'm using the below mentioned formula:

pd.merge(df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10, on = ['RSSD9999', 'RCFD0010','RCFD0071','RCFD0081','RCFD1400','RCFD1773','RCFD2123','RCFD2145','RCFD2160','RCFD3123','RCFD3210','RCFD3300','RCFD3360','RCFD3368','RCFD3792','RCFD6631','RCFD6636','RCFD8274','RCFD8275','RCFDB530','RIAD4000','RIAD4073','RIAD4074','RIAD4079','RCFD1403','RCON3646','RIAD4230','RIAD4300','RIAD4301','RIAD4302','RIAD4340','RIAD4475','RCFD1406','RCFD3230','RCFD2950','RCFD3632','RCFD3839','RCFDB529','RCFDB556','RCON0071','RCON0081','RCON0426','RCON2145','RCON2148','RCON2168','RCON2938','RCON3210','RCON3230','RCON3300','RCON3839','RCONB528','RCONB529','RCONB530','RCONB556','RCONB696','RCONB697','RCONB698','RCONB699','RCONB700','RCONB701','RCONB702','RCONB703','RCONB704','RCON1410','RCON6835','RCFD2210','RCONA223','RCONA224','RCON5311','RCON5320','RCON5327','RCON5334','RCON5339','RCON5340','RCON7204','RCON7205','RCON7206','RCON3360','RCON3368','RCON3385','RIAD3217','RCFDA222','RCFDA223','RCFDA224','RCON3792','RCON0391','RCFD7204','RCFD7206','RCFD7205','RCONB639','RIADG104','RCFDG105','RSSD9017','RSSD9010','RSSD9042','RSSD9050'],how='outer')

But I'm getting an error "merge() got multiple values for keyword argument 'on'". I think the code is correct, can anyone help me to understand whats wrong here?

Comment: Ignoring the issues with the merge() command, you have given us no idea what is in `df1-df10`.

Comment: Df1 - Df10 are the names of my data frames. All the files may or may not contain all the variables mentioned in the formula.

Comment: So thanks for getting back.  But you did not understand what I said.  I guessed what `df` stood for but I can not guess what is in your dataframes. We need to know what the data looks like to be able to help.  To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you are using 10 dataframes to merge. Ok it's possible but all dataframe should have atleast one column should have same.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.Dataframe(data,column=[your columns],index=[index names])
df=df.set_index(common co)
# do for all ten dataframes
answer=pd.merge(df,df1........,df10,on=column name,how='outer')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pd.merge(Ray, Bec, Dan, on = 'Key', how ='outer')
```